# No Grub2 boot manager window after installing Ubuntu 14.10 over Linux Mint 17

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.10

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 update 1 and I installed Linux Mint 17 trough dualboot and everything worked great so when I start my laptop I get a Grub2 bootmanager window where I can choose between Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint. A couples of weeks ago there was a new update for Ubuntu (Ubuntu14.10) so I tried to install it over Linux Mint. Ubuntu 14.10 was installed and I had to reboot my laptop after that I got a message: "Grub resque". Finally I found a way to bypass the grub2 resque error so I could start Linux Mint 17.1 Live cd (trough usb) and installed Linux Mint 17.1 on the sda5 partition (I format Ubuntu completely). So I solved the Grub2 resque error by creating a new partition with bios_grub flag (2mb) because the previous bios_grub partition was deleted. The only problem I still get is that when I start my laptop he boots into Windows 8.1 so I have to start my laptop and push F11 for the BIOS Boot Manager and then I can choose between Windows boot manager or Ubuntu or ubuntu (when I choose Ubuntu or ubuntu the Grub boot screen appears and I can choose Linux Mint 17.1 rebecca). So the problem is I get no Grub2 boot menu when I start my laptop (also push shift doesn't works). The problem begin after installing Ubuntu 14.10 over Linux Mint 17. I tried to install Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Fedora and Linux Mint Debian Edition but everytime I start my laptop it start straight to Windows 8.1. I tried grub-customizer to change some settings but still no grub2 window when I start my laptop.

My boot info script from Boot-Repair is on the url below.

I hope my question/problem is clear now. Big Thanks.

http://paste2.org/yp5xwy81

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than "not grub2 boot manager".

Comment: I mean the grub2 window where I can choose which os to boot from when I start my pc.

Comment: Yes, we know what grub2 is but we don't know exactly what happens on your system. Did it completely disappear? What happens when you boot then? Did you configure it not to appear? Have you tried pressing a key like <shift> when it boots and seeing if grub appears?

Comment: Hope my problem is clear now. 

Comment: There is no Grub2 window anymore also pressing shift doesn't works. When I start my laptop Windows 8.1 boots. Luckily I find a way to boot into Linux...start laptop -> press F11 -> Windows Boot Manager appears then I press HDD and I see Windows boot manager, Ubuntu, ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, much much better, thanks. One last thing though: If you added some paragraph breaks it would be more readable :)

Comment: If you have a bios_grub partition, that is for BIOS/CSM boot, but your Windows is in UEFI boot mode. The two modes are not compatible and grub menu will only boot systems installed in the same boot mode. Best if all systems are installed in UEFI boot mode. And how you boot installer is how it installs. You can use Boot-Repairs advanced mode to uninstall grub-pc(BIOS) and install grub-efi(UEFI) to convert to UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your /boot/grub/grub/cfg file for the settings of "timeout". If your settings is "timeout=0", then the menu will not display.

There is also:

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT
    Wait this many seconds for a key to be pressed before displaying
    the menu.  If no key is pressed during that time, boot
    immediately.  Unset by default.

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET
    In conjunction with `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT', set this to`true' to
    suppress the verbose countdown while waiting for a key to be
    pressed before displaying the menu.  Unset by default.

To edit this (grub.cfg) file you need Grub Customizer:

sudo add-apt-archive ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer